# XML parsing Complexity

Tags: java, xml-parsing

```
<root>
    <nodes>
        <headnode>
            <info>Sometext1</info>
        </headnode>
        <leafnode>
            <info>sometext2</info>
        </leafnode>
        <leafnode>
            <info>sometext3</info>
        </leafnode>
    </nodes>

    <nodes>
        <headnode>
            <info>Sometext4</info>
        </headnode>
        <leafnode>
            <info>sometext5</info>
        </leafnode>
        <leafnode>
            <info>sometext6</info>
        </leafnode>
    </nodes>
</root>
```

I have the above Document to parse in the server side inside a JavaBean. I have to extract the `<info>` from the `<headnode>` of every  children.

I have tried to parse this with Java DOM but I cant get into the sublevels of the tree using

```
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("nodes");
```

But I cant iterate further down and unable to retrieve ... from each `<headnode>` of every `<nodes>` tag. Please help.

Comment: Take a look at JQuery, it was designed for iterating over the DOM.

Comment: @Richard sorry I didnt mention that I'm parsing the XML document from the server side, inside a Java Bean

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Please provide your actual code and the output or stack traces you are getting that makes you think it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get the `<info>` text from every `<headnode>` in your XML:

```
NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("headnode");
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    Node node = nodeList.item(i);
    NodeList childList = node.getChildNodes();
    for (int j = 0; j < childList.getLength(); j++) {
        Node childNode = childList.item(j);
        if (childNode.getNodeName().equals("info")) {
            String info = childNode.getTextContent();
            System.out.println(info);
        }
    }
}
```